# Best way to query mysql for total time worked in a day

Tags: mysql, math, time

I'm trying to come up with the best way to add the total time an employee was clocked in.

The punch types are **day in, break out, break in & day out**. You would think I could just select * where date = DATE, but that doesn't work if the employee arrived at 11:30pm and left at 2:00am the following day.

I was thinking something like this might be the best solution, but I don't know if it's practical or even possible:

Select * from the LAST RECORD where employee = employee STOP at the first instance of "clock in".

This would gather all the punches since the employee last clocked in. For example:

ID  NAME  TYPE  TIME

45  John  Day In  TIME

46  Joe  Day In  TIME

47  Mary  Break Out  TIME

48  Joe  Break Out  TIME

49  Joe  Break In  TIME

50  John  Day Out  TIME

51  Mary  Break In  TIME

52  Joe  Day Out  TIME

53  Mary  Day Out  TIME

So in the example I was thinking about, if you're looking for Joe's time, it would start searching from punch id 53 backwards until it reached punch 46. The result would be punches 46, 48, 49 and 51. I could then calculate the total time worked. Again, I don't know if this is even possible.

I would REALLY appreciate any comments/suggestions in regards to how to accomplish this, or any other ways that might be more practical to do this!

Comment: Seems like it might be nice if the database were structured differently. When someone punches in, you record it, and when someone punches out, you find their most recent punch-in and add an out time to it. But I assume that's out of your control, or it's got a different reason to be structured this way.

Comment: I agree with @Jefromi.  Changing the structure of the database would make the system much easier to work with.  It would also make it easier to find situations where people forgot to punch out.  Although this may not be in your control.

Comment: I'll restructure it any way that is needed... that's why I ask for any other suggestions. What would be best???

Comment: @user971230: I'm no database design expert, and I don't know all of your requirements, but if your main one is knowing how long people have been there, the structure I suggested in my first comment is a reasonable starting point.

Comment: It would be simpler but I need to keep track of if it's a break clockout or a day clockout. I need to be able to see if an employee is clocked out for the day or on break. PS- Thats part of my question- how would i find **the most recent** punch in?

Comment: @Oseer - I know this is a very old question, but did you end up figuring out how to do it?  I am working basically the exact same problem and would like to see what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the problem down into steps, firstly list all 'IN' records:

```
SELECT p_in.*
FROM punches p_in
WHERE p_in.type = 'IN'
```

Next, write a subquery to find the next 'OUT' record (this method assumes id is auto-incremented for simplicity):

```
        SELECT MIN(pa.id)
        FROM punches pa
        WHERE pa.type = 'OUT'
        AND pa.name = p_in.name
        AND pa.time > p_in.time
```

Now, wrap this query in an outer select that looks like the punches table:

```
    SELECT pb.id, pb.name, pb.type, pb.time
    FROM punches pb
    WHERE pb.id = (
        SELECT MIN(pa.id)
        FROM punches pa
        WHERE pa.type = 'OUT'
        AND pa.name = p_in.name
        AND pa.time > p_in.time
    )
```

And use this in a LEFT JOIN to the original query:

```
SELECT
    p_in.id     in_id,
    p_in.name   in_name,
    p_in.type   in_type,
    p_in.time   in_time,
    p_out.id    out_id,
    p_out.name  out_name,
    p_out.type  out_type,
    p_out.time  out_time
FROM punches p_in
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pb.id, pb.name, pb.type, pb.time
    FROM punches pb
    WHERE pb.id = (
        SELECT MIN(pa.id)
        FROM punches pa
        WHERE pa.type = 'OUT'
        AND pa.name = p_in.name
        AND pa.time > p_in.time
    )
) p_out
WHERE p_in.type = 'IN'
```

This will give you a result set where each 'in' record has the next corresponding 'out' record. If there is no corresponding out record, the out values will be set to null.

Hopefully you can use these result to calculate what you need.

Comment: Wow... This looks amazing but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. The mysql fields are "punch_id" (auto increment), "emp_id" (employee id), punch_type, punch_time (timestamp). I'm trying to update my PHP page to use the code you've provided but the names in your example are a little confusing to me. Could you suggest how to do this using the field names I've provided? I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the employee Id, the punch type Id, but you are missing the day or period Id, which will make things a lot easier:

```
PunchId  PeriodId  Employee  PunchTypeId  PunchDateTime
-------- --------- --------- ------------ --------------
...
44       1         Mary      Day In       TIME
45       1         John      Day In       TIME
46       1         Joe       Day In       TIME
47       1         Mary      Break Out    TIME
48       1         Joe       Break Out    TIME
49       1         Joe       Break In     TIME
50       1         John      Day Out      TIME
51       1         Mary      Break In     TIME
52       1         Joe       Day Out      TIME
53       1         Mary      Day Out      TIME
54       2         John      Day In       TIME
55       2         Mary      Day In       TIME
56       2         Joe       Day In       TIME
...
```

Then you can use something like:

```
select di.Employee, di.PeriodId, 
    timediff(do.DayOutTime, bi.BreakInTime)
    + timediff(bo.BreakOutTime, di.DayInTime) as PeriodWorkedHours
from
(
    select Employee, PeriodId, PunchDateTime as DayInTime
    from punches
    where PunchTypeId = 'Day In'
) as di
inner join (
    select Employee, PeriodId, PunchDateTime BreakOutTime
    from punches
    where PunchTypeId = 'Break Out'
) as bo on di.Employee = bo.Employee and di.PeriodId = bo.PeriodId
inner join (
    select Employee, PeriodId, PunchDateTime as BreakInTime
    from punches
    where PunchTypeId = 'Break In'
) as bi on di.Employee = bi.Employee and di.PeriodId = bi.PeriodId
inner join (
    select Employee, PeriodId, PunchDateTime as DayOutTime
    from punches
    where PunchTypeId = 'Day Out'
) as do on di.Employee = do.Employee and di.PeriodId = do.PeriodId
```

That is assuming that within a PeriodId all employees have four punches each (Day In, Break Out, Break In, and Day Out).  Also, the PeriodId should not be tied to the date to handle the case you mention in your question, when punch times cross day boundaries. Rather, increment the PeriodId for an employee after inserting the last punch for the period (i.e. Day Out punch).

Comment: One problem this may cause is that there may not be four punches in a day. An employee may not take a break. I'm going to dig through this though, thank you for your suggestion. The period ID idea has got me thinking...

Answer (score 0):

I would use query like the next:

```
select workerid, sum(case 
when punchtype = 'in' then -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
when punchtype = 'out' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
when punchtype = 'bin' then -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
when punchtype = 'bout' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
end )/60 as WorkingHours
from Punchlog
group by workerid
```

Remarks: 
Lets assume I have table:

```
create table PunchLog
(workerid int not null,
punchtime datetime not null,
punchtype char(4) not null)
```

with punch data from few days.

Lets put some test data:

```
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (1, '20110901 23:30', 'in')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (1, '20110902 03:30', 'out')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (1, '20110902 00:15', 'bin')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (1, '20110902 01:15', 'bout')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (2, '20110901 09:30', 'in')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (2, '20110901 17:00', 'out')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (2, '20110901 14:30', 'bin')
insert into PunchLog (workerid, punchtime, punchtype) values (2, '20110901 10:00', 'bout')
```

Time person spent at working place is:

```
T = out - in - (bin -bout) = out - in -bin + bout
```

where `in`, `out` is day punch time and `bin`, `bout` is break punch time.

If I will group by `workerid` and apply sum() to `punchtime` then I will have working time BUT I need `in` and `bin` time were negative. Also I cannot sum datetime. Thus I will change `punchtime` to span from any date in the past and use case statement to set sign:

```
sum(case 
when punchtype = 'in' then -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
when punchtype = 'out' then DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20110901', punchtime)
. . .
end )/60 as WorkingHours
```

in my test it produces result:

```
workerid  WorkingHours
--------  ------------
1         5
2         3
```